# Is there a reason why a Script times out on one spreadsheet, but not the next?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having a large spreadsheet copy and paste to over a dozen other spreadsheets using a timed trigger each day. The script works for everyone but not for one spreadsheet in particular:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NJfCbZjqpLCxNniJ96QiT_51y0Hd11H36SuFTyTVB_A/edit?usp=sharing

For this sheet as an example of the functioning ones, the script takes about 30s and works: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tbnQYQrwfKN9yk48e5g48Lj18tLmE9iEYL6U80e4DMs/edit?usp=sharing

For the first sheet, it times out. My goal is to have it actually work!

Turned it into an array which cut down on the time from just a values copy, but it didn't help the first link above.

```
//code that times out
function CopyDataToNewFile7() {
  const source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1sX6VTyedVLBL57EMSuD7cqUwe9GzoCRajLZhA1ZBJ3Q').getSheetByName('Final'); // sss = source spreadsheet


  const destination8=SpreadsheetApp.openById('1NJfCbZjqpLCxNniJ96QiT_51y0Hd11H36SuFTyTVB_A');//Jordan fixed



 const target8 =   destination8.getSheetByName('All Team Data')



const dataToCopy = source.getDataRange().getValues();

   result = [];


  for (i=0; i<dataToCopy.length;i++){
  result.push(dataToCopy[i]);

  }



target8
         .getRange(1,1,result.length,result[0].length).setValues(result);
}
```

```
//code that works
function CopyDataToNewFile8() {
  const source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1sX6VTyedVLBL57EMSuD7cqUwe9GzoCRajLZhA1ZBJ3Q').getSheetByName('Final'); // sss = source spreadsheet


  const destination15=SpreadsheetApp.openById('1tbnQYQrwfKN9yk48e5g48Lj18tLmE9iEYL6U80e4DMs');//Mandee





  const target15 =  destination15.getSheetByName('All Team Data');




const dataToCopy = source.getDataRange().getValues();

   result = [];


  for (i=0; i<dataToCopy.length;i++){
  result.push(dataToCopy[i]);

  }



target15
         .getRange(1,1,result.length,result[0].length).setValues(result);



}
```

Should copy and paste in well under a minute, but does not and times out. Any thoughts?

Error message I'm seeing: Service timed out: Spreadsheets (line 266, file "Code")

Line of code:

```
.getRange(1,1,result.length,result[0].length).setValues(result);
```

Comment: Any reason you cannot delete all those empty rows and columns in the All Team Data sheets?  This will speed things up quite a bit.  For instance, in the file not working you would go from 57,000 + rows to under 4,000 and would also loose 10 columns.

Comment: @Karl_S I did that, but it is still timing out. Otherwise, it's basically the same document as the spreadsheet that is working.

Comment: Have you run this through the [debugger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints) with multiple breakpoints to see when it times out?

Comment: @Karl_S It times out at this line:         
    .getRange(1,1,result.length,result[0].length).setValues(result);

Comment: Try changing that to 2 lines and see how long it takes to complete the first half if it does at all. The two lines would be `var range = target15.getRange(1,1,result.length,result[0].length);` and then ` range.setValues(result);` It will still timeout someplace, yuo just need to figure out where.  Of course, you also need to note how long it takes to get to this point in case all the time is taken up prior to this point and this is just where you get before the actual time limit is reached. Basically you have x minutes for the entire run.